# What do you get if you take the inverse of f using a subset when f isn't surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So if you have $f:A \to B$, and T $\subseteq$ A, and $\mathrm{}^{-1}: B \to A$, and f isn't necessarily surjective, then lets say...
$f(T)$ $\to$ {$1,2,3$}, but an element in $T$ maps to both $1$ and $2$. Then what would $f(${$1,2,3$} map to?

In context, the problem asks if $T ⊆ \mathrm{}^{-1}
(f(T))$ and then part (b) is if $\mathrm{}^{-1}(f(T)) \subseteq T$

EDIT: I guess my question now is if $T ⊆ \mathrm{}^{-1}
(f(T))$ is true or false, and how that compares/is that different than $\mathrm{}^{-1}(f(T)) \subseteq T$

Comment: Use `\to` to get a right arrow in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: A function cannot map any element to two distinct elements.

Comment: So it necessarily has to be injective? What would the difference between the two questions be then?

Comment: If $f$ isn't necessarily surjective, how do you define $f^{-1}:B\to A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if $f$ is a function and $T$ is contianed in the domain of $f$ then $T\subseteq f^{-1}(f(T))$. The set $f^{-1}(f(T))$ is by definition, the set of points in the domain of $f$ which are mapped by $f$ into $f(T)$, the points in $T$ have this property by the definition of $f(T)$.

It is not always true that $f^{-1}(f(T))\subseteq T$, as there can be points not in $T$ which are mapped to the same points as elements of $T$. However, if $f$ is injective then this is always true as that can't happen. The surjectivity of $f$ implies nothing about either of these containments.

Comment: Yes, it's an issue with injectivity, not surjectivity. This leads me to another question: If $f(x) = 1$, so a constant function, is $\mathrm{}^{-1}(1) = A$? Given $f: A \to B$

Comment: @MattWeiler by definition $f^{-1}(1)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=1\}$ and since $f(a)=1$ for all $a\in A$, then $f^{-1}(1)=A$.